# Solver for a dense matrix almost diagonally dominant

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Just wanted to know whether there is a name for class of real matrices that are square, non symmetric and have the property that the diagonal element is exactly the negative of the sum of the other elements in a row.

\begin{equation}
A_{ii} = - \sum_{i\neq j, j=1}^{j=N}A_{ij} \qquad i = 1, 2, \ldots,N \qquad; A_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

Also, is there a known efficient solver for $Ax = b$ for such a matrix.

Comment: Maybe the matrix could be viewed as some variant of a graph Laplacian? If in addition, you know that the matrix is non-singular and that the diagonal entries are positive (maybe same sign is enough) then I think conjugate gradient would work. The Girshgorin circle theorem would guarantee SPD.

Comment: @ShawSa 1) Alas this type of matrix is always singular (see my answer) 2) What do you mean by SPD ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Ah yes. My perspective was coming from numerical PDEs where finite difference matrices approximating the Laplacian operator fit this description (loosely). Hence my connection with graph Laplacians as a generalization. I forgot they are always singular as you mentioned. I suppose this is analogous to a discretization with Neumann boundary conditions. By SPD I meant "symmetric positive definite" though I suppose I really meant to just say positive definite / positive eigenvalues (non-negative since it's singluar). Anyway, I was just spit-balling ideas that sounded relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these matrices have a specific name, but they are clearly *characterized* by the fact that they have column vector $U=(1,1,\cdots,1)^T$ in their kernel (otherwise said, it is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $0$).

Concerning a method for solving system $Ax=b$:

In fact, as such $N \times N$ matrices have a non-trivial kernel, their rank is at most $N-1$. Therefore, there will not be in general a single solution but an infinity of solutions, obtained by adding to a particular solution the general element of the kernel which is $tU$:

$$S=(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_N) \ \text{is a solution} \ \implies \ $$ $$\forall t, \ S=(x_1+t,x_2+t,\cdots x_N+t) \ \text{is a solution.}$$

OR have zero solutions like in this case:

$$\begin{cases}-2x+y+z&=&3\\
x-2y+z&=&2\\
x+y-2z&=&1\end{cases}$$

where, if you add the 3 equations, you find

$$0=6$$

the contradiction coming from the fact that no $(x,y,z)$ is solution of this system.